# Generating Entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am currently converting a project from CodeIgniter to Symfony2.

I am now working with the [generation of entities](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html). As I was doing the steps from the Symfony Documentation and run the following commands:

```
php app\console doctrine:generate:entity AppBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\metadata\orm\Product
```

suddenly cmd gave me the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]
Too many arguments.

doctrine:generate:entity [--entity="..."] [--fields="..."] [--format"..."] [--with-repository]
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: There is a white-space between `doctrine` and `generate:entity`.

Comment: @Andariel Sorry for the typo. there's no space between `doctrine` and `:generate:entity` when I run those commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should launch just

```
 php app\console doctrine:generate:entity
```

No parameters needed, it will take everything from your current config